# Python ElementTree doesn't seem to recognize text nodes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse a simple XML document located at http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx/getAirportInformationByAirportCode?airportCode=jfk using the ElementTree module.  The code (so far):

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement

url = "http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx/getAirportInformationByAirportCode?airportCode=jfk"
s = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print s

document = ElementTree.parse(s)
root = document.getroot()
print root
dataset = SubElement(root, 'NewDataSet')
print dataset
table = SubElement(dataset, 'Table')
print table
airportName = SubElement(table, 'CityOrAirportName')
print airportName.text
```

The final line yields "none" not the name of the airport in the XML.  Can anyone assist?  This should be realtively simply, but I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents) for that module.  It says, among other things:

> The SubElement() function also provides a convenient way to create new sub-elements for a given element

In particular note the word **create**.  You are **creating** a new element, not reading the elements that are already there.

If you want to locate certain elements within the parsed XML, read the rest of the documentation on that page to understand how to use the library to do that.